# button onclick function is unnecessarily reloading the page after the function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Here is a button onclick which calls a function. When this button is clicked after the function execution, the page is getting reloaded in firefox browser.

```
<button id="next" class="submit" type="submit" onclick="onNextEvent()" return false;>Next</button>
```

When

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

are removed from this
function, the page is getting reloaded in Chrome browser.I am using Jquery jquery - 1.9.1.js.Please help!Thanks

```
function onNextEvent() {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
            .next().show().addClass('current');
        $('#prev').show();
        $('#prev').attr('disabled', null);
        $('#skip').show();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: event is not defined, declare it as a parameter in your function

Comment: Is this button inside a form? please post more html. If the button is inside a form then its default action would be to submit the form and the page would refresh. If you do not want that then the answers given below will do the job

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onNextEvent(event) 
{   
   event.preventDefault();

/* Rest of code */
```

Or

```
function onNextEvent(event) 
{   
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();

/* Rest of code */
```

Answer (score 0):

The return false statement should be implemented together with the onclick like this:

```
<button onclick="onNextEvent(); return false;">
```

Or, the function called can return false:

```
 function onNextEvent() {
    //function code
    return false;
 }
```

I have used the first way several times and it always worked for me.